# the one point compatification of $ ‎(‎‎\mathbb{Q}‎‎‎‎,‎\tau ‎)‎ $

Tags: general-topology

The topological space $(X,\tau)$ is said to be C - C iff the closed sets in $X$ coinside with the compact set in $X$.

> The bellow example show that $(‎‎\mathbb{‎Q}‎‎^{‎‎\star‎‎}‎,‎‎‎ ‎\tau‎^{‎\star‎} ‎)‎ $‎  is C - C.

let$ ‎(‎‎\mathbb{Q}‎‎‎‎,‎\tau ‎)‎ $‎  be the space of rationals with the relative toplogy and  let$ (‎‎\mathbb{‎Q}‎‎^{‎‎\star‎‎}‎,‎‎‎ ‎\tau‎^{‎\star‎} ‎)‎ $‎  be the one point compatification of $ ‎(‎‎\mathbb{Q}‎‎‎‎,‎\tau ‎)‎ $‎. since $ ‎(‎‎\mathbb{Q}‎‎‎‎,‎\tau ‎)‎ $‎ is not locally compact it follow that$ (‎‎\mathbb{‎Q}‎‎^{‎‎\star‎‎}‎,‎‎‎ ‎\tau‎^{‎\star‎} ‎)‎ $‎ is not Hausdorff. To show that$ (‎‎\mathbb{‎Q}‎‎^{‎‎\star‎‎}‎,‎‎‎ ‎\tau‎^{‎\star‎} ‎)‎ $‎  is C - C , it suffices to show that every compact subset of X is closed.

Let A be a compact subset of X:

case(1) : suppose that  ‎‏‎$ ‎\infty ‎\not‎\in A $ . then   $ A‎ ‎‎\subset‎‎ ‎‎\mathbb{‎Q}‎ $ and  thus  A is compact in $ ‎(‎‎\mathbb{Q}‎‎‎‎,‎\tau ‎)‎ $. But ‎$ ‎(‎‎\mathbb{Q}‎‎‎‎,‎\tau ‎)‎  $‎‎ is Hausdorff and hence A is both closed and compact in ‎$ ‎(‎‎\mathbb{Q}‎‎‎‎,‎\tau ‎)‎  $‎‎. then by definition of the one point compatification $ X‎‎‎‎‎\setminus A‎ ‎‎\in  ‎‎‎‎\mathbb{‎Q}‎‎^{‎\star‎‎}‎‎ $ ‎‎ and hence A is closed in$ (‎‎\mathbb{‎Q}‎‎^{‎\star‎‎}‎,‎‎‎ ‎\tau‎^{‎\star‎‎} ‎)‎ $‎‎‎.

case (2) : suppose that $  ‎\infty ‎‎‎‎\in ‎A‎ $ and A is not closed in  $ (‎‎\mathbb{‎Q}‎‎^{‎\star‎‎}‎,‎‎‎ ‎\tau‎^{‎\star‎‎} ‎)‎ $. Take $ x ‎‎\in  ‎A‎^{d}  ‎\cap(‎ X ‎‎‎‎\setminus A‎ ‎)‎ $‎ ,$ ‎A‎^{‎d}‎ $‎  being the derivd set of  A in  $ (‎‎\mathbb{‎Q}‎‎^{‎\star‎‎}‎,‎‎‎ ‎\tau‎^{‎\star‎‎} ‎)‎ $. Then$ x‎ ‎‎\in‎‎ ‎‎‎\mathbb{‎Q}‎ $‎‏  and there exists for each positive integer $i $, an  $ ‎a_{i}‎ ‎\in A‎ ‎‎\setminus ‎\{ ‎\infty‎ ‎\}‎ $‎  s.t ‎$  ‎a_{i} ‎\longrightarrow‎ ‎ ‎x‎ $ in both ‎$ ‎(‎‎\mathbb{Q}‎‎‎‎,‎\tau ‎)‎  $ and $ (‎‎\mathbb{‎Q}‎‎^{‎\star‎‎}‎,‎‎‎ ‎\tau‎^{‎\star‎‎} ‎)‎ $. without loss of generality we may assume that in the natural order  $ ‎a_{1} >‎ ‎a_{2} >‎ ‎‎\ldots >‎ ‎a_{n} >‎ ‎‎\ldots >‎ ‎x‎ $‎. Let ‎$ F‎ =‎ ‎\{ ‎x\}‎  ‎\bigcup ‎\{  ‎a_{i}‎  ‎\mid  i‎ =‎ ‎1, ‎2,‎ ‎\ldots ‎\}‎ $‎. Clerly  $F$ is closed and compact in $ (‎‎\mathbb{Q}‎‎‎‎,‎\tau ‎)‎ $ and thus ‎$ X‎ ‎‎\setminus F‎ ‎‎\in‎‎ ‎‎‎‎\mathbb{‎Q}‎‎^{‎\star‎‎‎}‎ $‎.‎‎‎. Let $ O_{‎i}‎‎‎‎‎ = \{ r ‎\mid r‎ >‎ ‎a_{i+1}   ,‎\quad‎   ‎‎‎ r‎ ‎‎\in‎‎ ‎‎\mathbb{‎Q} ‎\} ‎\quad  ‎\forall‎  i ‎‎\in ‎\mathbb{Z}‎^{‎+‎}‎‎‎‎‎$‎ . Then $O_i$ is open in both  $ ‎‎\mathbb{‎Q}‎ $‎ and ‎$ ‎‎\mathbb{‎Q}‎‎^{‎\star‎‎‎}‎ $‎  for each $i$ . Now ‎$ A ‎‎\subset‎‎ ( X ‎\setminus ‎F‎ ) ‎ \cup\bigcup‎‎ ‎\{ O_{i}   ‎\mid  i =‎1, 2,‎\ldots \}‎‎‎‎‎$‎  which is an open cover of A from $ ‎‎\mathbb{‎Q}‎‎^{‎\star‎‎‎}‎ $‎ . this open  cover of A  containe  no finitesubcover. Thise  is  a contradiction.

> Why in case (2 )can we say :
>
> "**(1) :there exists** for each positive integer $i $, **an **  $ ‎a_{i}‎ ‎\in A‎ ‎‎\setminus ‎\{ ‎\infty‎ ‎\}‎ $‎ ** s.t ‎**$  ‎a_{i} ‎\longrightarrow‎ ‎ ‎x‎ $ in both ‎$ ‎(‎‎\mathbb{Q}‎‎‎‎,‎\tau ‎)‎  $ and $ (‎‎\mathbb{‎Q}‎‎^{‎\star‎‎}‎,‎‎‎ ‎\tau‎^{‎\star‎‎} ‎)‎ $"
>
> **(2) :** 
>   $ O_{‎i}‎‎‎‎‎ = \{ r ‎\mid r‎ >‎ ‎a_{i+1}   ,‎\quad‎   ‎‎‎ r‎ ‎‎\in‎‎ ‎‎\mathbb{‎Q} ‎\} ‎\quad  ‎\forall‎  i ‎‎\in ‎\mathbb{Z}‎^{‎+‎}‎‎‎‎‎$‎ . Then $O_i$ **is open in both**  $ ‎‎\mathbb{‎Q}‎ $‎ and ‎$ ‎‎\mathbb{‎Q}‎‎^{‎\star‎‎‎}‎ $‎  for each $i$.?
>
> (3) : $ A ‎‎\subset‎‎ ( X ‎\setminus ‎F‎ ) ‎ \cup\bigcup‎‎ ‎\{ O_{i}   ‎\mid  i =‎1, 2,‎\ldots \}‎‎‎‎‎$‎  which is an open **cover of A from** $ ‎‎\mathbb{‎Q}‎‎^{‎\star‎‎‎}‎ $‎ . this open  cover of A  **containe  no finitesubcover**.?

Comment: What's with the weird spacing?

Answer (score 1):

Apart from minor notational differences and some errors in transcription this is taken verbatim from Norman Levine, ‘When are Compact and Closed Equivalent?’, *The American Mathematical Monthly*, Vol. $72$, No. $1$ (Jan. $1965$), pp. $41$-$44$, Example $1$.

1. We have $\infty\in A$ and $x\in(\operatorname{cl}_{\tau^*}A)\setminus A$. Clearly $x\ne\infty$, so the topologies $\tau$ and $\tau'$ agree at $x$. Let $\mathscr{B}=\{B_i:i\in\Bbb Z^+\}$ be a countable nested local base at $x$ in $\Bbb Q$; then $\mathscr{B}$ is also a local base at $x$ in $\Bbb Q^*$, and $B_i\cap(A\setminus\{\infty\})\ne\varnothing$ for each $i\in\Bbb Z^+$. Thus, for each $i\in\Bbb Z^+$ we can pick a point $a_i\in B_i\cap(A\setminus\{\infty\})$, and the sequence $\langle a_i:i\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ then converges to $x$ in both $\Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb Q^*$.
2. Recall that at this point we have $a_1>a_2>\ldots>a_n>\ldots>x$. For each $i\in\Bbb Z^+$ we set $O_i=\{r\in\Bbb Q:r>a_{i+1}\}$; this is just the open ray $\Bbb Q\cap(a_{i+1},\to)$, so of course it’s open in $\Bbb Q$, i.e., $O_i\in\tau$. But $\tau\subseteq\tau^*$, so $O_i\in\tau^*$, and therefore $O_i$ is open in $\Bbb Q^*$.
3. $\bigcup_{i\in\Bbb Z^+}O_i=\{r\in\Bbb Q:r>a_{i+1}\text{ for some }i\in\Bbb Z^+\}$. Recall that $\langle a_i:i\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ is a strictly decreasing sequence converging to $x$, so for any $r\in\Bbb Q$ we must have $$\exists i\in\Bbb Z^+(r>a_{i+1})\quad\text{iff}\quad r>x\;,$$ i.e., $\bigcup_{i\in\Bbb Z^+}O_i=\{r\in\Bbb Q:r>x\}$. In particular, $F\setminus\{x\}=\{a_i:i\in\Bbb Z^+\}\subseteq\bigcup_{i\in\Bbb Z^+}O_i$. Let $V=\Bbb Q^*\setminus F$; $F$ is closed and compact in $\Bbb Q$, so $V$ is open in $\Bbb Q^*$, and therefore $W=V\cup\bigcup_{i\in\Bbb Z^+}O_i$ is open in $\Bbb Q^*$. Let $a\in A$; $x\notin A$, so $a\ne x$, and therefore either $a=a_i$ for some $i\in\Bbb Z^+$, or $a\in A\setminus F$. if $a=a_i$ for some $i\in\Bbb Z^+$, then $a\in\bigcup_{i\in\Bbb Z^+}O_i\subseteq W$, and if $a\in A\setminus F$, then $a\in V\subseteq W$. In all cases, therefore, $a\in W$, and hence $A\subseteq W$. Thus, $\{V\}\cup\{O_i:i\in\Bbb Z^+\}$ is an open cover of $A$ in $\Bbb Q^*$. Suppose that $F$ is a finite subset of $\Bbb Z^+$; then $\{V\}\cup\{O_i:i\in F\}$ does not cover $A$. To see this, let $j=\max F$; then $\bigcup_{i\in F}O_i=O_j=\{r\in\Bbb Q:r>a_{j+1}\}$, and it follows that $a_i\notin V\cup\bigcup_{i\in F}O_i$ for each $i>j$.